# Will the Hubble parameter reach zero asymptotically in the far future?

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

In the current accelerated expansion universe model will the Hubble parameter $H$ reach zero asymptotically in the far future?

Answer (score 9):

No, but it will asymptotically approach a particular value. In the Standard Model where dark energy is a cosmological constant, the Hubble parameter is a function of the present-day Hubble constant and the radiation (R), matter (M), curvature (K), and dark energy ($\Lambda$) densities as follows
$$
H(a) = \frac{\dot{a}}{a} = H_0\sqrt{\Omega_{R,0}\,a^{-4} + \Omega_{M,0}\,a^{-3} + \Omega_{K,0}\,a^{-2} + \Omega_{\Lambda,0}},
$$
with
$$
\begin{gather}
H_0 = 67.3\;\text{km}\,\text{s}^{-1}\text{Mpc}^{-1},\quad \Omega_{R,0}\approx 0, \\ 
\Omega_{M,0} = 0.315,\quad \Omega_{\Lambda,0} = 0.685, \quad \Omega_{K,0} = 0,
\end{gather}
$$
according to the latest Planck results. So in the far future, the scale factor $a$ goes to infinity, and we get
$$
H(\infty) = H_0\sqrt{\Omega_{\Lambda,0}} \approx 55.7\;\text{km}\,\text{s}^{-1}\text{Mpc}^{-1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!Very specific!I had some doubt about but now it's more clear!

Comment: Could the Hubble parameter asymptotic value of ~ 55.7 reached as the time tends to infinity be in principle considered as fundamental physical constant (as the speed of light in the vacuum is)?